# Intellij Idea, another file incorporation to main function JAVA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to coding and I guess it's a stupid question, but I got lost on the internet with jars, constructors, interfaces, imports and so on..
I need to make two files - one with an information about the program and the second with a main in it. In JAVA. Could someone demonstrate it to me with a simple hello, world! example or a few different prints? One in a different file from a the main function. I work with IntelliJ IDEA.

I hope the question is understandable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the [basic introductory Hello World from IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html)?

Comment: basically, this is the first 2 or three chapters in any textbook

Comment: I have checked it. And since I'm very new to programming I either don't understand it, or in my opinion it doesn't tell me anything about the two files that I want to merge. One with a main in it and the other with functions. I'm not even sure if I should import the other file, or package it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello World program in Java

Steps to Compile and Run first Java program:

1. Declare a class with name `A`.
2. Declare the main method `public static void main(String args[]){}` in another Main class (`MainB`)
3. Now Type `System.out.println("Hello World");` which displays the text Hello World.

Example: (Assuming both classes in same package demo)

A.java

```
package com.demo;

public class A {

    private String name = "Hello World.!";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

MainB.java

```
package com.demo;

public class MainB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since the OP wants to have two files (classes)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Updated answer.

Comment: Shouldn't I somehow "import" A.java to the other file? As I was working with C language we made a main.c, function.c and function.h (header file). The header file was like a link between the two other files.

Comment: assuming both in same package no need of importing. else you need to import

Comment: @Meta Bambalaite If I answered your question, Could you please mark the answer as useful. Thank you